# Aws Athena - is it possible to query a JSON property that has dots in name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I use Athena for querying data stored in JSON objects in S3.

Some JSON properties contain dots in their names, they represent Android application names.

The property looks this way:

```
{
  "MessageTime": "2019-09-24T16:07:16+00:00",
  "Memory": {
    "com.google.android.gms.maps": {
      "Min": 0,
      "Max": 0,
      "Avg": 0
    }
  }
}
```

The AWS Athena table with such column is successfully created and can be queried.
Is there a way to refer to **Memory.com.google.android.gms.maps.Min** property in SQL query?

Probably I can rename this column somehow when I create the table, etc?

I can query on other embedded properties (without dots in the names) easily.

Comment: Per SQL standard, when referring to a column with dots, you need to `"`-quote the name. E.g. `SELECT "Memory.com.google.android.gms.maps.Min"  FROM ...`.

Comment: Tried that, Athena returns - SYNTAX_ERROR: line 9:40: Column '...' cannot be resolved

Comment: When you `SHOW COLUMNS` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-columns.html), how is this column listed?

Comment: only outer column names are shown in that case, I see `Memory`

Comment: The `Memory` column is defined this way:

Memory struct<
 Total:struct<`Min`:int,`Max`:int,`Avg`:int>,
 `com.companyname.appname1`:struct<`Min`:int,`Max`:int,`Avg`:int>,
 `com.companyname.appname2`:struct<`Min`:int,`Max`:int,`Avg`:int>
              >

Comment: Try `"Memory"."com.companyname.appname1"."Min"` (or `"Memory"."com.google.android.gms.maps"."Min"`).

Comment: it works this way, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the way the table has been created.

- If there is a `Memory` column of type `string` you can use [`json_extract`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html#json_extract) to get the value: `json_extract("Memory", '$[\'com.google.android.gms.maps\'].Min')`
- If there is a `Memory` column of type `map<string,string>` you can use a combination of [`element_at`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/map.html#element_at) and [`json_extract`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html#json_extract): `json_extract(element_at("Memory", 'com.google.android.gms.maps'), '$.Min')`
- If there is a `Memory` column of type `map<string,struct<Min:int,Max:int,Avg:int>>` you can use [`element_at`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/map.html#element_at) and dots to access the value: `element_at("Memory", 'com.google.android.gms.maps').Min`

I'm not sure how to declare the `Memory` column as `struct`, perhaps it's possible to escape the dots in that syntax, but I'm unsure how. Either way it doesn't look like it's a struct kind of structure, it looks more like a map.

Comment: Defined `Memory` as `map<string,struct<Min:int,Max:int,Avg:int>>`. Thank you for help.

Comment: I had to use double quotes to access the field using `json_extract`
`json_extract("Memory", '$["com.google.android.gms.maps"].Min')`